# Avoid the iphone go into sleep mode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, sleep-mode

I have made an iphone fitness application. 
The issue i am unable to resolve here is that, while the application is running, the iphone goes in the sleep mode, and hence the accelerometer and sound turns off. Which i dont want to happen.

Is there anyway i can avoid this from happening? If not that, atleast i could increase the time of my iphone to go into sleep mode.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been searching for that for too long now.

Answer (score 11):

As Jacob and epatel said, the `[[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES ];` is the way you wanted. However, you'd better to implement when the application is interrupted by other signal. It means that you'd implement `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method.

Because, there are enforced interruption on the iPhone/iPod touch. A phone call, push a power button, and so on.

Comment: KatokichiSoft, could you add an example of how to implement this method?

Comment: I put this code into (void)applicationWillResignActive, but it only works in the new iPad version. It does not work in the previous version iPad (just be older a little bit)